# need insight with logstash and elk

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to add in data from logstash to elastic search bellow is the config file and the result on the terminal

```
    input {
     file {
    path => "F:/business/data/clinical_trials/ctp.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "C:/Users/matth/Downloads/logstash-7.14.2-windows-x86_641/logstash- 
    7.14.2/data/plugins/inputs/file/.sincedb_88142d557695dc3df93b28d02940763d"
   }
   }

    filter {
      csv {
        separator => ","
        columns => ["web-scraper-order", "web-scraper-start-url", "First Submitted Date"]
     }
     }

     output {
    stdout { codec => "rubydebug"}
  elasticsearch { 
  hosts => ["https://idm.es.eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243"]
  index => "DB"
   user => "elastic"
  password => "******"
}
}
```

and when i run i get the following it gets right down to the piplines and the next step should be establishing connection with elastic but it hangs on pipeline forever.

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
C:/Users/matth/Downloads/logstash-7.14.2-windows-x86_641/logstash-7.14.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:200: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
Sending Logstash logs to C:/Users/matth/Downloads/logstash-7.14.2-windows-x86_641/logstash-7.14.2/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2021-09-22T22:40:20,327][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Log4j configuration path used is: C:\Users\matth\Downloads\logstash-7.14.2-windows-x86_641\logstash-7.14.2\config\log4j2.properties
[2021-09-22T22:40:20,333][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.14.2", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.19.0 (2.5.8) 2021-06-15 55810c552b OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.12+7 on 11.0.12+7 +indy +jit [mswin32-x86_64]"}
[2021-09-22T22:40:20,383][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2021-09-22T22:40:21,625][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2021-09-22T22:40:22,007][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 46 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 120 keys and 417 values
[2021-09-22T22:40:22,865][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["https://idm.es.eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243"]}
[2021-09-22T22:40:23,032][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[https://elastic:xxxxxx@idm.es.eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243/]}}
[2021-09-22T22:40:23,707][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"https://elastic:xxxxxx@idm.es.eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243/"}
[2021-09-22T22:40:24,094][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch version determined (7.14.1) {:es_version=>7}
[2021-09-22T22:40:24,096][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
[2021-09-22T22:40:24,277][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>12, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>1500, "pipeline.sources"=>["C:/Users/matth/Downloads/logstash-7.14.2-windows-x86_641/logstash-7.14.2/config/logstash-sample.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x52ff5a7a run>"}
[2021-09-22T22:40:24,346][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using a default mapping template {:es_version=>7, :ecs_compatibility=>:disabled}
[2021-09-22T22:40:24,793][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>0.51}
[2021-09-22T22:40:24,835][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2021-09-22T22:40:24,856][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ][main][c4df97cc309d579dc89a5115b7fcf43a440ef876f640039f520f6b116b913f49] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
[2021-09-22T22:40:24,876][INFO ][logstash.agent         ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, `:running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}

any help as to why my data isnt getting to elastic???  please help
```

Comment: Do file changes get printed to stdout?

Comment: try removing your `sincedb` definition, add in `nul`, remove your Elasticsearch output and restart Logstash to see if you get something in `stdout`. if you do then it's your `sincedb`

Comment: so i took off the elastic out put and the below is the error i get now just trying to run a standard output

Comment: [ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", \"input\", \"filter\", \"output\" at line 27, column 1 (byte 1713) after ",